# Update a label with array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I need to update all content of my Arraylist in a label. if my arraylist content is: [0]a; [1]b; [2]c
the label will show: a b c
i tried to do it, but I'm blocked here:

```
private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\\text.txt";
        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    }
```

how can I continue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi Vale, if the solution below has helped can you [mark it as resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [String.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___) like this?

```
string path = @"C:\\text.txt";
label1.Text = String.Join(" ", File.ReadAllLines(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming your Label is called Label1 you can use `String.Join()`**

> **`String.Join()`** : **Concatenates the elements of a specified array or**
>   **the members of a collection, using the specified separator between**
>   **each element or member.**

**Updated Code**

```
private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"C:\\text.txt";
    string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path); //
    label1.Text = String.Join(" ", readText); // a b c
}
```

**Input:** `[0]a,[0]b,[0]c`

**Output:** `a b c`

Comment: If only that had been suggested ten minutes before you did?...